# mongoose getting <Reversed Proxy> when not using subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I log a user that I made with schema in mongoose, I get something named `<Revoked Proxy>,` so that I can not loop over this `links` array, or do anything to it

```
model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    activePaths: StateMachine { paths: [Object], states: [Object] },
    skipId: true
  },
  '$isNew': false,
  _doc: {
    _id: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
    username: 'turur',
    password: 'asdf',
    email: 'turur@gmail.com',
    categoryLinks: [ [EmbeddedDocument], [EmbeddedDocument] ],
    links: <Revoked Proxy>,
    imagelink: '/images/blank',
    plan: '0',
    bakiye: 0,
    phoneNumber: 766951259,
    __v: 14
  }
}
```

The schema is as follows, only the `links` matter here,

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
   },
  password: String,
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true
   },
  categoryLinks: {
    type: [categoryLinkSchema],
    validate: [function(doc) {
        for(let d of doc){
            const duplicates = this.categoryLinks.filter(function(c){
                return c.link === d.link || c.label === d.label;
            })
            if(duplicates.length > 1){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }, 'Each categoryLinks.label must be unique.']
  },
  links : { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  imagelink: String,
  plan: String,
  bakiye: Number,
  phoneNumber: Number
});
```

When I try to push something to the `links` array for the user, I try this but this seem not to be the correct,

```
  userModel.findOne({
    username: req.session.username
  }).then(
    (user) => {
      console.dir(user)
      res.render('takip-ettigim-indirimler', {links: user.links});
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      console.log('Error at login phase: ' + error.code + " error: " + error);
    }
  );
```

This seem to not work, so should I use `[EmbeddedDocument]` like I did with `categoryLinks` or is there a way to do it with just `links : { type : Array , "default" : [] },` declaration?